# Repeating pattern of empty lines

Tags: code-golf, string

Write the shortest program or function that takes some text as input, and outputs either it or an empty line in a repeating pattern:

```
some text
some text

some text
some text

some text
some text

...
```

This must continue indefinitely, or until some unpreventable limitation occurs (stack size, memory, etc.). It must be newline separated, and you can assume the inputted text is made up of non-newline printable ASCII characters. Note that it doesn't have to follow the pattern text-text-empty, and text-empty-text would be equally valid.

The ratio of text lines and empty lines will also be specified by input. There are various ways you can do this (though you only need to support one):

- A fraction represented as a floating point number (this can represent the fraction which do OR do not have text in them, but it must be consistent)
- A ratio of lines with text to lines without (represented as two integer inputs)
- A fraction of lines which do OR do not have text in them (represented as an integer numerator and denominator)

Example:

Text: `Hello, world!`
Ratio: `2:3`

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!



Hello, world!
Hello, world!



...
```

Text: `fraction`
Fraction: `1/3`

```
fraction


fraction


fraction


...
```

Text: `decimal decimal decimal`
Input: `0.6`

```
decimal decimal decimal
decimal decimal decimal
decimal decimal decimal


decimal decimal decimal
decimal decimal decimal
decimal decimal decimal


...
```

Text: `example with a different pattern`
Fraction: `2/5`

```
example with a different pattern

example with a different pattern


example with a different pattern

example with a different pattern


...
```

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes, per language, wins.

Comment: Just to make sure, answers can pick one of the ways to input and do not need to support all of them, right?

Comment: @Laikoni Yes, they only need to support one.

Comment: Would [this answer](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfo1CnxNZA09Yu3bbY1q6gKDOvRKMkTqNE27ZQ077YSl1dUy1do1jzf5qGgZ6ZpoZSSmpyZm5ijpLmfwA) be valid? Or do we have to strictly follow the pattern _p lines with the string / q empty lines_?

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, that's fine. They don't have to be strictly in that order. I'll also add a test case showing that.

Comment: Note that another potential issue with my output is that it's not a _repeating_ pattern.

Comment: @Arnauld I think if, when divided into chunks as many lines long as the fractional representation denominator, each one would need to be identical for it to be valid.

Comment: does the output need to be consistent across multiple calls?

Comment: @att No, as long as all of the other rules are met I guess.

Comment: I might post an 1+ solution later - that is, after I finished the 1+ solution of Space Cleaners! and Verify Brainfuck program.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms For codes that hit the integer limit and are stuck printing the same line, are those valid? For example, the PHP and the Java solutions get stuck printing just `Hello world!` forever (no empty lines), once they hit the highest positive integer, for the first test case.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yeah, any limits caused by hardware or uncontrollable language design are fine.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Including using a counter and expecting it to fail, when other (longer) aproaches can be used that don't use any of those counters and works properly forever?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You could, I suppose, but an answer that runs forever would be much more interesting. It's like creating a language that happens to do this challenge with a builtin. Valid, but not interesting.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms But the question is if that is a valid answer or not? Personally, I think it goes against the spirit of the challenge, but I'm not the one who made the challenge: you are. As such, I'm asking your opinion as I've raised the issue about 2 answers that go to the integer limit and then print incorrectly after. From my understanding, the challenge is to always output the correct output, until something external stops the code from running (timeout, exception, stackoverflow, ...).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I would count integer limit as something external. Expecting every answer to use bigints or even just the largest integer size available isn't optimal either. Purposely implementing something to stop it after a certain point, or making an answer only work until a certain point (excluding integer size/memory/etc.) wouldn't be allowed. I think it's sort of a case-by-case thing, and in most cases I think going with a reasonable sized integer, like short, int, long, etc. isn't intentionally going against the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms The thing is, changing the code slightly (but to make it longer) can make the integer limit go away. For example, the Java solution is `(s,n,d)->{for(int i=0;;)System.out.println(i++%d<n?s:"");}`. Changing it to `(s,n,d)->{while(true)for(int i=0;i<d;)System.out.println(i++%d<n?s:"");}` will make it so that it never reaches the integer limit. The PHP answer can be changed to operate this way too. Yes, the code is longer, but it never reaches to the integer limit and doesn't print the wrong output at the integer limit.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'd say they're valid. The ones that work forever could be posted in a separate answer, though, sort of as a different category (like different languages)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I believe it is better if you add that information into the post, just in case the comments are purged.

Answer (score 6):

### [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>26</s> 12 bytes

```
T0{LbPaLcPx}
```

-14 bytes after taking ratio as two arguments.

#### Explanation:

```
T0           Till 0 (infinite loop)
  {Lb        Loop b(second argument) number of times
     Pa      Print a(first argument) with newline
       Lc    Loop c(third argument) number of times
         Px} Print x(empty string) with newline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/xKDaJykg0Sc5oKL2////aUWJySWZ@Xn/Df8bAwA)

Comment: Or I should find a way to print a plain newline. I'll ask about that.

Comment: @Dingus Fixed it.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>67 ..</s>  38 bytes

```c
i;f(s,a,t){for(;puts(i++%t<a?s:""););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk2jWCdRp0SzOi2/SMO6oLSkWCNTW1u1xCbRvthKSUnTWtO69r9yZl5yTmlKqoJNcUlKZr5ehh1XZl6JQm5iZp6GpkI1F2eahpJHak5OvkJ4flFOiqKSjpGOqaY1V@1/AA)

- Thanks to @att for 11 byte saved and to @ErikF for 7 bytes saved!

Takes input as string, number of printed lines, total lines.

<s>We flush buffer at every iteration.</s>

puts() returns non negative if no error occours, hope it doesn't return 0 either!

Comment: Is `fflush` necessary? You also don't need to initialize `i`.

Comment: @att right! Flush not necessary at all and for initialized `i` I think you are right, normally a function should be reusable but since this overflows that's fine

Comment: `int` and `char*` are the same size in TIO, so you don't actually need the type specifier (-7 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk2jWCdRp0SzOi2/SMO6oLSkWCNTW1u1xCbRvthKSUnTWtO69r9yZl5yTmlKqoJNcUlKZr5ehh1XZl6JQm5iZp6GpkI1F2eahpJHak5OvkJ4flFOiqKSjpGOqaY1V@1/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
def f(t,a,b,n=0):print(n%b<a)*t;f(t,a,b,n+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0QnUSdJJ8/WQNOqoCgzr0QjTzXJJlFTq8QaLqedqPk/TUPJIzUnJ1@hPL8oJ0VRSUfBSEfBVPM/AA)

Prints until exceeding max recursion depth, which the challenge seems to allow. As a program:

**45 bytes**

```python
t,a,b=input()
n=0
while 1:print(n%b<a)*t;n+=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v0QnUSfJNjOvoLREQ5Mrz9aAqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0QjTzXJJlFTq8Q6T9s28f9/JY/UnJx8hfL8opwURSUdBSMdBVMA)

The idea is to to use a counter `n` that cycles through values modulo `b`, and only print the text if this is from `0` to `a-1`, and otherwise print a blank line. We could also do `n+=1` in place of `n+=a` to get a different pattern where the text and blank lines come in clumps rather than mixed throughout.

It almost works to use a float input for the density as below:

**40 bytes** (not working)

```python
def f(t,p,n=0):print(n%1<p)*t;f(t,p,n+p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0SnQCfP1kDTqqAoM69EI0/V0KZAU6vEGiqjXaD5P01DySM1JydfoTy/KCdFUUlHwUDPTPM/AA)

The issue is float imprecision -- a number like `12.6` might have its decimal part be very slightly bigger or smaller than `0.6`. This method would work for irrational densities as well, limited precision aside.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program. Prompts for text, then for ratio of lines with text to lines without (as two integers). Runs forever.

```apl
⎕←⍣≢↑⎕/⍞''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jvqmP2iY86l38qHPRo7aJQK7@o9556uog2f8KYFDA5ZGak5Ovo1CeX5SToshlpGAMAA)

`⍞''` prompt for text and juxtapose with an empty string

`⎕/` prompt for replication factors and replicate

`↑` stack them on top of each other

`⍣≢` repeat until the value changes (i.e. never):

`⎕←` output

Comment: This is probably the only language where "assignment" is a function (as opposed to a syntax) *and* can be modified by the "repeat" higher-order function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to Dion

```python
def f(t,a,b):
 while 1:print((t+'\n')*a+'\n'*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNo0QnUSdJ04pLoTwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0RDo0RbPSZPXVMrEUxrJWn@T9NQ8kjNyclXKM8vyklRVNJRMNJRMNb8DwA)

`t` is the text to print, `a`:`b` is the ratio of lines of text to empty lines.

Comment: save a byte by removing a space in the start of the second line?

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>17</sup> 16 bytes

```
$:,[echo@#'',:~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Vax0olOTM/IdlNXVdazqYv9rchkpGCukKah7pObk5CuE5xflpCiq/wcA)

Note: If the empty lines cannot have spaces, then `$:,[echo@>@#a:;~]` works for 17 bytes.

### how

Uses a kind of "fork bomb" recursion:

- `$:` - calls entire verb again
- `,` - then append...
- `[echo@#` - the echo of the left argument applied as a line-wise multiplier to...
- `'',:~]` - the right argument catted line-wise with an empty string

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Runs until the stack overflows. More golfing to follow ...

```
ÆOpWÃVÆOpPÃ©ß
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xk9wV8NWxk9wUMOp3w&input=MiwzCiJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhIg)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>34</del> 33 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: be82 00ad 2d30 3092 52fe ca7c 0956 ac3c  ....-00.R..|.V.<
00000010: 0dcd 2975 f95e b00a cd29 fece 75eb 5aeb  ..)u.^...)..u.Z.
00000020: e7                                       .
```

Listing:

```
BE 0082     MOV  SI, 82H        ; SI to command line tail 
AD          LODSW               ; load first two chars 
2D 3030     SUB  AX, '00'       ; ASCII convert          
92          XCHG AX, DX         ; DL = numerator, DH = denominator 
        PATT_LOOP: 
52          PUSH DX             ; save original numerator/denominator 
        FRAC_LOOP: 
FE CA       DEC  DL             ; decrement numerator 
7C 09       JL   LF             ; if less than 0, just display LF 
56          PUSH SI             ; save start of input string 
        CHAR_LOOP: 
AC          LODSB               ; load next char of string 
3C 0D       CMP  AL, 0DH        ; is it a CR? 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write to console
75 F9       JNZ  CHAR_LOOP      ; if not a CR, keep looping 
5E          POP  SI             ; restore start of input string 
        LF: 
B0 0A       MOV  AL, 0AH        ; LF char 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write to console
FE CE       DEC  DH             ; decrement denominator 
75 EB       JNZ  FRAC_LOOP      ; if not 0, keep looping 
5A          POP  DX             ; restore numerator/denominator
EB E7       JMP  PATT_LOOP      ; start over and loop indefinitely
```

Standalone DOS executable, input via command line.  First two chars are numerator / denominator, followed by input string.

[image]

[image]

*(note: program slightly altered to only repeat 3 times for screenshots)*

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ø.x⁹ẋṄ€1¿
```

A full program accepting the ratio as a list `[empty, full]` and the string which prints forever.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDL2KR407H@7qfriz5VHTGsND@////x9trGMU@1/dA6gmX0ehPL8oJ0VRHQA)**

#### How?

```
Ø.x⁹ẋṄ€1¿ - Main Link: list of integers, ratio ([empty, full]); list of characters, text
                                e.g.: [3, 2]; "Hello, world!"
Ø.        - bits                      [0, 1]
  x       - times (ratio)             [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
   ⁹      - chain's right argument    "Hello, world!"
    ẋ     - repeat (vecorises)        ["", "", "", "Hello, world!", "Hello, world!"]
        ¿ - while...
       1  - ...condition: 1 (always)
      €   - ...do: for each:
     Ṅ    -          print with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 58 bytes

```java
(s,n,d)->{for(int i=0;;)System.out.println(i++%d<n?s:"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Ba8MwDIXv@xVaYBBTN4zBLvPaXncZDHocO2ixUtw5crCVbqPkt2dO6x3Ekx687@mIJ1wf7dfcekwJXtExnG8AHAvFDluCN5S8Xl2AU3AWIg2EUu8lOj6A0I/oJQA89hRRQryeljj0jhdDmZye8gzjp3ctJEHJcqH1ubOw3j@gU6Xpv3coupnrpFlbtd6euxDrpcFt7o1R@98k1DdhlGbIFPFcu9Xqzj7zLj1VlTLTbC7IgmrK/9ULeR/gO0RvbysNDxoey6PT/Ac)

### Credits

- 4 bytes saved thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).

Comment: If you take the input as a fraction-pair (i.e. taking `2/5` as input `[2,5]` instead of `[2,3]`), you can golf the `(n+b)` to `b` (naming that variable `d` for denominator in that case would make more sense than `b`).

Comment: What will happen when `i` is the highest positive value? Will it wrap to the negatives? Will it crash?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it will go to the negatives, but who cares, this is code golf, we don't take those into account: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is close enough to infinity for most purposes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Quoting the challenge: "This must continue indefinitely, or until some unpreventable limitation occurs (stack size, memory, etc.)." If after `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the results are wrong, I don't know if the answer is valid. According to https://tio.run/##NY5Ba8MwDIXv@xVaYBBTN4zBLvPaXncZDHocO2ixUtw5crCVbqPkt2dO6x3Ekx687@mIJ1wf7dfcekwJXtExnG8AHAvFDluCN5S8Xl2AU3AWIg2EUu8lOj6A0I/oJQA89hRRQryeljj0jhdDmZye8gzjp3ctJEHJcqH1ubOw3j@gU6Xpv3coupnrpFlbtd6euxDrpcFt7o1R@98k1DdhlGbIFPFcu9Xqzj7zLj1VlTLTbC7IgmrK/9ULeR/gO0RvbysNDxoey6PT/Ac what happens is that the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` line repeats

Comment: Well, an integer going back to negative is an unpreventable limitation, right?

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>100</s> <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```
	T =INPUT
	CODE('N' DUPL(';	OUTPUT =T',INPUT) DUPL(';	OUTPUT =',INPUT) ':(N)')	:(N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNEwdbTLyA0hIvT2d/FVUPdT13BJTTAR0PdmtM/NAQooWAboq4DVqKJIQOXULfS8NNU1@QEUVyufi7//6cVJSaXZObncRlyGQMA)

Takes input as `TEXT`, `M`, `N` on separate lines.

Using the `CODE` function, this generates an infinite loop of

```
N; OUTPUT =T; OUTPUT =T ...; OUTPUT =; OUTPUT =; ... :(N)
```

Or equivalently (with `;` being replaced by newlines):

```
N
 OUTPUT =T
 OUTPUT =T
 ...
 OUTPUT =
 OUTPUT =
 ...
 OUTPUT =:(N)
```

Which it then enters with the final `:(N)` and never leaves.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 87 bytes

```
@set f=@for /l %%i in (1,1,
@set/ps=
:g
%f%%1)do @echo(%s%
%f%%2)do @echo(
@goto g
```

Takes the text and blank line counts as command line arguments and the text to repeat on standard input. Explanation:

```
@set f=@for /l %%i in (1,1,
```

Define what is effectively a macro for two very similar loops.

```
@set/ps=
```

Input the text.

```
:g
```

Begin an infinite loop.

```
%f%%1)do @echo(%s%
```

Print the text the desired number of times.

```
%f%%2)do @echo(
```

Print the desired number of blank lines.

```
@goto g
```

Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(t,c)repeat cat(rep(c(t,''),c),sep='
')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCoAgEADvvUK67C7sqc6@JWTbShAVNXq@Cd26DTMwpRfN6pqP5xZ81Gr7cUdpPkVsLPRVI67hQJQhAWgErpotTED/Ac6XhpDYPKmEfWbBhVei/gI)

Function with arguments specifying text `t` and vector `c` of counts of text & blank lines.

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYxBCoAgEADvvUK67C7sqc6@JWTbShAVNXq@Cd26DTMwpRfN6pqP5xZ81Gr7cUdpPkVsLPRVI67hQJQhAWgErpotTED/Ac6XhpDYPKmEfWbBhVei/gI)

Comment: Thanks again Giuseppe!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[s`¶×?F=
```

First input is the text, second input is a pair `[amount_of_nonempty_lines, amount_of_empty_lines]`; outputs the empty lines before the non-empty lines.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ujjh0LbD0@3dbP//90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUeSKNtJRMI4FAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
[         # Start an infinite loop:
 s        #  Swap the two (implicit) inputs, so the pair it at the top of the stack
  `       #  Pop and push its contents to the stack
   ¶×     #  Repeat a newline character "\n" the top value amount of times as string
     ?    #  Pop and output it without trailing newline
      F   #  Pop and loop the top value amount of times:
       =  #   And output the top string with trailing newline (without popping)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
~o¢+RøR⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vy7/0CLtoMM7gh41bvj//79ScX5uqkJJakWJ0n@j/8YA) This program takes the string, the number of lines with text, and the number of lines without text as three separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 40 bytes

Expects `(p, q)(s)`, where \$p/q\$ is the fraction of lines that have the string \$s\$ in them.

This runs until the call stack overflows.

```javascript
(p,q,t=0)=>g=s=>print(t++%q<p?s:'')&g(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcEJCoAgEADAr4RQ7qJBEEFEa28RSzEqvPD7NnPrqrNJPpSxrs1SgyCjLDQhKUeZVEj@K1CE6OMejrxxjoODjM3CLLsFgZ2X8a9@GLYf)

Answer (score 1):

### [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 236 bytes, 6 * 23 = 138 assembled bytes

Full program that takes the input in the order (`input string, numerator, denominator`). Output is to STDOUT.

```
.data
m:
.text
main:li$v0,8
la$a0,m
li$a1,99
syscall
li$v0,5
syscall
move$t0,$v0
li$v0,5
syscall
move$t1,$v0
s:li$t2,0
li$v0,4
la$a0,m
l:syscall
add$t2,$t2,1
blt$t2,$t0,l
li$t2,0
li$a0,10
li$v0,11
p:syscall
add$t2,$t2,1
blt$t2,$t1,p
b s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY29DsIwDIR3P0WGjlaVFJBo38YlroiUlKixSnn60B8FJsTg4Xzf3aXoQs61JSEIHdTCi0AgN3beVbPGK3iqSGOAVZPBtoX0SjfyHg7g8tHhMXMlGtfvD8/sXtqqpcFCnb8TXeHJ2g3ZzkDv5RAa99WSXTOmlBgD8U/aYIRepZx5oRA9q6eTuyJl3TDwxKOoSCI8jdDA6Q0)

### Explanation

```
.data
msg:                            # Here's the string input buffer (dynamically allocated)

.text
main:
    li $v0, 8                   # Set syscall code 8
    la $a0, msg                 # The first operand is the input buffer
    li $a1, 99                  # The second is the maximum length of input

    syscall                     # Read a line of characters from input

    li $v0, 5                   # Set syscall code 5
    syscall                     # v0 = integer from input
    move $t0, $v0               # t0 = v0

    li $v0, 5                   # Re-set syscall code 5
    syscall                     # v0 = integer from input
    move $t1, $v0               # t1 = v0

    start:                      # Main loop:
        li $t2, 0               #     t2 = 0 (our counter)

        li $v0, 4               #     Set syscall code 4
        la $a0, msg             #     First operand: the inputted message at msg
        loop:                   #     loop:
            syscall             #         Print the message at msg
            add $t2, $t2, 1     #         Increment counter
            blt $t2, $t0, loop  #         If t2 < t0, jump back

        li $t2, 0               #     Clear counter

        li $v0, 11              #     Set syscall code 11
        li $a0, 10              #     First operand: '\n'

        lop:                    #     second loop:
            syscall             #         Print character in a0
            add $t2, $t2, 1     #         Increment counter
            blt $t2, $t1, lop   #         if t2 < t1, jump back

        b start                 #     Jump back to the main loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
Do[Print@If[i>#2,#,""],∞,{i,#3}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yU/OqAoM6/EwTMtOtNO2UhHWUdJKVbnUcc8nepMHWXj2li1/2nRSh6pOTn5CuX5RTkpiko6RjrGsf8B)

Takes `[text, num, denom]`, where `num/denom` is the ratio of lines *without* text.

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate 0.84, 99 bytes

Yes, it is quite long, but it works!

```
{@callexplode intoM":",argv.1}{@while1}{@forfrom 1toM.0}{@echolargv.0}{@/}{@forfrom 1toM.1}{@echol}
```

Takes input in the form of an array with the format `['text', '1:1']`.

---

If taking input as 2 separate numbers (`['text', 1, 1]`) is acceptable, the code can be reduced to this (66 bytes):

```
{@forfrom 1toargv.1}{@echolargv.0}{@/}{@forfrom 1toargv.2}{@echol}
```

---

**Ungolfed:**

Below is a more readable version of the top code:

```
{@call explode into ratio ":", argv.0}
{@while true}
    {@for i from 1 to ratio.0}
        {@echo argv.0, EOL}
    {@/}
    {@for i from 1 to ratio.1}
        {@echo EOL}
    {@/}
{@/}
```

Notice that `{@echol}` and `{@echo EOL}` do the same thing: output whatever, ending with a newline.

---

You an try it on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abf48bd44a808e91f130d4a390fcb8a18d6ded39

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```php
for($a=$argv;;)echo($i++%$a[3]<$a[2]?$a[1]:"")."
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbVUSi9LLrK01U5Mz8jVUMrW1VVUSo41jbYCkUaw9kDSMtVJS0tRT4lKy/v//f3FJaUlJapFCZnFOYl7Kf@P/pgA)

Nothing new under the sun: PHP arguments and vars prefix eating bytes.. Will go on "forever" (until it overflows the max integer value, and starts using floats for `$i`, then probably the legendary precision for big floats will cause inconsistent results)

EDIT: newline replaced by.. a newline to save 1 byte

Comment: By the time it reaches to the point where it loses precision, you will be stuck on an infinite loop. It seems to be at `PHP_INT_MAX`, where `PHP_INT_MAX + 1 == PHP_INT_MAX` is true. So, it will be forever stuck here. But, depending on the execution environment, this **may** be a valid answer: if you read https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time  you will see that the default is 0 (no timeout) for the console/command line. This means that, with `php -r`, with a default `php.ini`, your code will fail after `$i = PHP_MAX_INT`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes that's expected, IMO the answer falls into the "or until some unpreventable limitation occurs (stack size, memory, etc.)" case, so I guess it's allright

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel at least in TIO it seems to [behave as I expected it would](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVTIVbBUCPALiPf1C4n0dI6y5yhKL4lNKcws0VDI1rblUMrW10cT@/wcA) when it reaches `PHP_MAX_INT`

Comment: The problem is that at `PHP_MAX_INT`, it will be stuck printing the same exact line, instead of producing the expected output. At `PHP_MAX_INT`,  whatever result is on `PHP_MAX_INT%$a[3]<$a[2]`, it will print that line **forever**. Please check this example: https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkVTIVbBUCPALiPf1C4n0dI6y5yhKL4lNKcws0VDI1rblUMrW10cT@/wcA

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes that's exactly what I meant by "will cause inconsistent results", but I don't understand why you blame this specific answer, it's exactly what will happen for most other answers when their variables will overflow (if not a straight crash). Again, that was expected in the question with ""or until some unpreventable limitation occurs (stack size, memory, etc.)"". I even took the time to explain clearly how it would happen in my answer!

Comment: That's actually something preventable. It requires rewritting the code, but is preventable. Just add `<?` to the code and point to the 30 second timeout. And then, the limitation becomes the 30 seconds where the script quits automatically, instead of getting stuck on printing the exact same line.  Yes, you can remove the timeout in the code itself, but honestly, it's rarely done.